# Is there an alternative to UNION that does fewer scans?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

See the [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xjHdxku1CMHm6ZY6LmwhB1/2).

On the following table

```
CREATE TABLE foo (x INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, y INTEGER);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES (0,41), (1, 23), (2,45), (3,32), ...
```

I need the `x` and `y` which has `min(y)` over groups of 10 `x`, and the same for `max(y)`:

```
SELECT x, min(y) FROM foo GROUP BY (x/10)
UNION
SELECT x, max(y) FROM foo GROUP BY (x/10);
```

The `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` output shows that two scans of the table are performed

```
`--COMPOUND QUERY
   |--LEFT-MOST SUBQUERY
   |  |--SCAN TABLE foo
   |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
   `--UNION ALL
      |--SCAN TABLE foo
      `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

**Is there any way to reword the query so that only one scan is performed?**

What I've done in the mean time is to select all rows (`SELECT x, y FROM foo;`) and manually aggregate min/max as rows are returned to the host language:

```
int lastGroup = 0;
while (sqlite3_step(query) == SQLITE_ROW) {
  int x = sqlite3_column_int(query, 0);
  int y = sqlite3_column_int(query, 1);
  int group = x / 10;
  if (group != lastGroup) {
    // save minX, minY, maxX, maxY in a list somewhere
    // reset minX, minY, maxX, maxY
    // ...
    lastGroup = group;
  }  
  else {
    if (y < minY) {
      minX = x;
      minY = y;
    }
    else if (y > maxY) {
      maxX = x;
      maxY = y;
    }
  }
}
```

This achieves a single scan and the whole process is more than twice as fast... but I'd rather express this logic *declaritively* in SQL if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do one `group by` with more columns?

On the following table

```
SELECT (x/10) * 10, min(y), max(y)
FROM foo
GROUP BY (x/10)
```

If you want multiple rows, you can unpivot afterwards:

```
SELECT x, (CASE WHEN x.which = 1 THEN min_y ELSE max_y END) as min_max_y
FROM (SELECT (x/10) * 10 as x, min(y) as min_y, max(y) as max_y
      FROM foo
      GROUP BY (x/10)
     ) f CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 1 as which UNION ALL SELECT 2) x;
```

EDIT:

You are using a SQLite extension -- which is not consistent with the standard or any other SQL language.  A better way to write this uses window functions:

```
select x, y
from (select f.*,
             row_number() over (partition by (x/10) order by y asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by (x/10) order by y desc) as seqnum_desc
      from foo f
     ) f
where 1 in (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc);
```

Or, using `first_value()` if you don't like subqueries:

```
select distinct (x/10)*10,  -- this is not necessary but helps to make the purpose clear
       first_value(x) over (partition by (x/10) order by y asc) as x_at_min_y,
       min(y) over (partition by x/10) as min_y,
       first_value(x) over (partition by (x/10) order by y desc) as x_at_max_y,
       max(y) over (partition by x/10) as max_y
from foo;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c8c4n6WwuyVbssBEX3m8tm/0) is a db-fiddle.

If you like, you can unpivot afterwards, as illustrated above.

Comment: @AndyMcoy . . . My bad.  I think SQLite may be the only database that doesn't support `floor()`.  But the integer division is fine, I just don't like to depend on that (some databases return 1/2 as 0, others as 0.5).

Comment: 1) I think the db fiddle you've linked points to the wrong fiddle.
2) I'm happy to use sqlite extensions, for now, if it makes the query easier to read.
3) I'm not sure how to apply your un-pivot query to your last, subquery-less, example.
Therefore I can't time your example. The `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` for your examples give me doubts though.

Comment: @AndyMcoy . . . That's why I don't usually use db-fiddle.  It is working now.

Comment: I've timed your 3rd and 4th snippet. They are 3 or 4 times slower than the original query, over hundreds of trials.

Comment: The 2nd snippet runs about 30% faster than the original query, but "unpivoting" would require a second scan through the original table. So overall I'm guessing it would be ~50% slower.

Comment: @AndyMcoy . . . I doubt the second does what you want anyway.